# static ChannelFactory in Global.asax.cs throws CommunicationObjectFaultedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, global-asax

I am using the following code in my Global.asax.cs file:

```
public static readonly IMyCommunicationService GlobalCommunicationChannel =
        new ChannelFactory<IMyCommunicationService>("NetTcpBinding_IMyCommunicationService").CreateChannel();
```

From every website I am accessing the static var "GlobalCommunicationChannel".

That is working very well so far. But sometimes, in production environment, I am getting an **CommunicationObjectFaultedException**. It says that I can not use my GlobalCommunicationChannel object as the object **"System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel" is in faulted-state**.

I get no more information than that. **After some minutes it is working again**. Don't know why. I think the connection is re-established or something like that.

What causes this error?
Is there a way to avoid this error in future without adding a try/catch and a retry everywhere?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Comment: What SessionMode and InstanceContextMode are you using?

Comment: InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple. 
Thread-safety is done on the server-end. As far as I understood I don't need do any thread safety on the client-end for the ServiceChannel.

Comment: But what about SessionMode?  It could be that your sessions aren't terminating.

Comment: I have not found any settings for SessionMode. Should it be over my MyCommunicationService class like InstanceContextMode  and ConcurrencyMode? Or is it something I have to add in web.config file? I think it is using the default value as I have not found this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your SessionMode value:

> By default, the value of this property
>   is Allowed, which means that if a
>   client uses a session-based binding
>   with a WCF service implementation, the
>   service establishes and uses the
>   session provided.  ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx))

In your service contract, try setting the session to NotAllowed.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
```

[By default, the maximum number of sessions a service host accepts is 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.servicethrottle.maxconcurrentsessions.aspx).  So you might check to see if your problem can be replicated in relation to 10 sessions.

Comment: Hello again. I have tried it, but now I get the following error:
Contract does not allow Session, but Binding 'NetTcpBinding' does not support Datagram or is not configured properly to support it.

Comment: I will try [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
instead.